# Stack returning copy because of inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my stack container adaptor to return from a getter by reference. Every time I try to make a getter to it even when using the reference operator it seems to be making a copy of it. I say this because whenever I debug and watch the container in one class the size of the container is 1 as expected since I pushed an object to the stack. However, once I enter another class via function...that class changes the size of the stack back to 0. Until I return back to what invoked the function then it returns back to 1.

Is it because I'm inheriting from the class that uses the container ?. Which goes on to my next question...Does inheritance make copies of the members in the mother class or does it reference them ? I'll try to explain this with minimal code so please be nice...

> ***GAME.HPP***

```
#ifndef GAME_HPP
#define GAME_HPP

#include <stack>
#include "GameState.hpp"

class Game
{
public: 
    Game();
    ~Game();

    int playGame();

protected:
    std::stack<GameState*>& getGStates();

private:
    std::stack<GameState*> gameStates; //GameState is a abstract class (no implementation)
    bool gameRunning;
};

#endif
```

> ***GAME.CPP***

```
int Game::playGame()
{
    gameRunning = true;

    SplashScreen sScreen; // SplashScreen inherits from GameState class
    gameStates.push(std::move(&sScreen)); //move screen to stack without making a copy

    // The stack size is now 1

    while (gameRunning)
    {
        gameStates.top()->runState();
    }
        return 0;
}

std::stack<GameState*>& Game::getGStates()
{
    return gameStates; //returns stack
}
```

> ***GAMESTATE.HPP***

```
#ifndef GAMESTATE_HPP
#define GAMESTATE_HPP

class GameState
{
public:
    GameState(){};
    ~GameState(){};

    virtual void runState() = 0;
    virtual void resumeState() = 0;
    virtual void pauseState() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
};
#endif
```

I do provide a good amount of implementation in the `SplashScreen` class, but if I remove it the problem will still persist. So for now to keep it simple I'll just say that its really no more different than what you see in the `GameState` header, but with blank blocks and returns. I'll still show the `runState()` bit but simplify it to scope the problem.

> ***SPLASHSCREEN.CPP***

```
//obvious header includes above

void SplashScreen::runState()
{
    std::cout << getGStates() << std::endl; //here the stack is 0
    std::cin.get(); //getting char from input stream so program won't terminate so fast
    return; //here I return to what invoke the runState() but stack becomes 1 again in the other class...Is a copy being returned by the getter ??
}
```

One thing that I want to mention though is that the `SplashScreen` class does  indeed inherit from `GameState` and the `Game` class. I inherit from the `GameState` class so I can use it as a interface for my `SplashScreen` class, and I inherit from the `Game` class so I can use the getter method.

Your probably saying why won't I just pass by reference through the function `runState()` in `Game.cpp`. I can and it'll work, but is there another way to do it without cluttering my function with parameters ? I don't want to have to add a parameter in every time I need something. Then again if I'm doing that my object design is poor, right ? Please help...

Comment: `SplashScreen sScreen; gameStates.push(std::move(&sScreen));` - no, no, no! That is not a safe way to manage memory.

Comment: @user2357112 Please enlighten me with your knowledge...What is the better way ?
.:(∩´ ﹏ `∩):.

Comment: That `SplashScreen` is going to self-destruct as soon as the scope of its definition ends. You'd need to dynamically allocate it, maybe with `new`, or restructure your program so it doesn't have to use `new`. And why does `SplashScreen` inherit from `Game`? A splash screen is not a game. It sounds like you haven't understood what inheritance actually *is*.

Comment: That splash screen has its own stack of `GameState` pointers. You're calling the splash screen's `getGStates` method, not the method of the object you need to be accessing. The splash screen doesn't even have any way to know about the `Game` object whose `getGStates` method you wanted.

Comment: @user2357112 Ooooh the reason I have `SplashScreen` inheriting from game was because I was seeing `SplashScreen` as a  part of the game, you know it being the first screen in all. I also was reading that GameStates are like separate programs/games within your Game which is why I did that. I guess that article I read was no good huh ?

Also, I'm aware that `SplashScreen` will terminate at the end block but `playGame` is actually my end block. My program runs states from other state classes and when the game is finished it returns back to `playGame` then terminates the loop.

Comment: Inheritance does not represent is-a-part-of relations. The splash screen might be part of the game, but that doesn't mean `SplashScreen` should inherit from `Game`. Inheritance represents is-a-kind-of relations.

Comment: @user2357112 Ahhh I see! Thanks for enlightening me. I really appreciate it :) I guess the reason why I'm having a such a  hard time is because my design is poorly constructed. By the way since your the only person here helping, is there another way for me to reference objects in classes from another class without passing by reference through a function ?

Comment: OT: moving plain pointers doesn't make much sense. If you want a pointer that represents ownership, use std::unique_ptr.

Comment: @n.m. To clarify that, that'll be `std::unique_ptr<std::stack<GameStack>> gameStates` , correct ? And then when I use the getter I should be able to access the gameStates stack in the `Game` class and not the copy ?

Comment: You have `std::stack<GameState*>`. Note the placement of `*`. If you want to replace the raw pointer with `std::unique_ptr`, that would be `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<GameStack>>`. `std::unique_ptr<std::stack<GameStack>>` would be something entirely different.

Comment: @n.m. Ok that makes sense, but how do I `push()` the object to the stack now. I'm getting this confusing  compiler error stating `no instance of overloaded function std::stack`

Comment: Comments are not suitable for such discussions, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that `SplashScreen` inherits from `Game`.
Therefore, the following code:

```
void SplashScreen::runState()
{
    std::cout << getGStates() << std::endl; //here the stack is 0
    std::cin.get(); //getting char from input stream so program won't terminate so fast
    return; //here I return to what invoke the runState() but stack becomes 1 again in the other class...Is a copy being returned by the getter ??
}
```

prints the stack for the `Splashscreen` instance object, not the initial `Game` instance object. In other words, the stack you print is not the same one you pushed the `SplashScreen` object to, or even a copy of that, but a completely unrelated `GameState` stack.

Your problem is: inheritance is not the right way to reason about the relationship between a `Game` and a `SplashScreen`. Inheritance mostly model "is a kind of" relationships between classes, and it looks like a SplashScreen is probably not a kind of Game. The kind of relationship you want to represent is a usage relationship, represented by referencing the object you're going to be using or passing it as parameter somewhere in the callstack.

If you need to access the game, you should probably:

1. add it as a member variable in your `SplashScreen` class, e.g.

   ```
   //Splashscreen.h
   class SplashScreen : public GameState {
       public:
       SplashScreen(Game& game)
       : m_game(game) {
       }

       ...    

       private:
       Game& m_game;
   }

   //SplashScreen.cpp
   void SplashScreen::runState()
   {
       std::cout << m_game.getGStates() << std::endl; //here the stack is 0
       std::cin.get(); //getting char from input stream so program won't terminate so fast
       return; //here I return to what invoke the runState() but stack becomes 1 again in the other class...Is a copy being returned by the getter ??
   }
   ```
2. or pass it as an argument to your runState method, e.g.

   ```
   void SplashScreen::runState(Game& game)
   {
       std::cout << game.getGStates() << std::endl; //here the stack is 0
       std::cin.get(); //getting char from input stream so program won't terminate so fast
       return; //here I return to what invoke the runState() but stack becomes 1 again in the other class...Is a copy being returned by the getter ??
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok say for example I declared my game object in main, and invoked `playGame()` like `game.playGame()`. What you said above still be referencing the same game object ?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I passed a `Game` reference argument to my `playGame()` function from `main`. Edited my `playGame()` function signature in `Game` so I can pass that reference of `Game` to everywhere I need to. Thanks a lot!